# Cannot connect to Infura inside a docker container: Cannot find module 'websocket'

Tags: go-ethereum, infura, docker

When I put my script in a docker container, I can no longer connect to Infura:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'websocket'
```

in package.json

```
"web3": "^1.0.0-beta.34"
```

in my script:

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider('wss://ropsten.infura.io/ws'));

myContract.events.Transfer({    // Transfer, allEvents, getPastEvents
    fromBlock: 0
}, function (error, event) {
    if (error) {
        console.log("error: " + error);
    } else {
        // console.log("event: " + JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
        console.log("event: " + event);
    }
})
```

My Dockerfile is pretty standard.

Any idea of what my problem is ?

Answer (score 3):

It seems inside a docker container, nodejs has problem getting the websocket from github. So I just add the websocket library directly in my app:

```
npm install --save websocket
```

Comment: I just ran into this as well. For whatever reason, inside of docker `"web3": "^1.0.0-beta.34"` doesn't install the "websocket" package. Seems like a bug in web3 or npm, no?